# Vue3 can't get dynamic styling to only apply to specific buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, styling

I am in the process of learning vue and I'm stumped on how to get these buttons to dynamically style separately when clicked.  These are filters for a list of products and I would like the apply one style when the filter is 'on' and a different style when the filter is 'off'.  I can get the styles to update dynamically, but all of the buttons change style when any of them are clicked.  The actual filter functionality is working as expected (the products are being filtered out when the button for that product is clicked).

In the code snippet, mode is passed to the BaseButton component, which is then applied as the class.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="genus of genusList" :key="genus.label">
            <BaseButton @click="filterGenus(genus.label)"  :mode="genusClicked.clicked ? 'outline' :''">
                {{ genus.label }}
            </BaseButton>
        </li>
        <BaseButton @click="clearFilter()" mode="flat">Clear Filter</BaseButton>
    </ul>
    </template>



    methods: {
        filterGenus(selectedGenus) {
            this.clickedGenus = selectedGenus
            this.clicked = !this.clicked
            this.$emit('filter-genus', selectedGenus)
        },
        clearFilter() {
            this.$emit('clear-filter')
        }
    },
```

I have tried making a computed value to add a .clicked value to the `genusList` object but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: The template and methods are in the same place, or is it a parent/child? Please put more effort into your question here. Also, how do you have `off/on` in your example? Tried with an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet (if you need more buttons to be styled at once save selected in array, if only one just save selected):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      genusList: [{label: 1}, {label: 2}, {label: 3}],
      selGenus: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isSelected(selectedGenus) {
      return this.selGenus.includes(selectedGenus)
    },
    filterGenus(selectedGenus) {
      if (this.isSelected(selectedGenus)) {
        this.selGenus = this.selGenus.filter(s => s !== selectedGenus)
      } else {
        this.selGenus = [...this.selGenus, selectedGenus]
      }
      this.$emit('filter-genus', selectedGenus)
    },
    clearFilter() {
      this.selGenus = []
      this.$emit('clear-filter')
    }
  },
})
app.component('baseButton', {
  template: `<button :class="mode"><slot /></button>`,
  props: ['mode']
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.outline {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="genus of genusList" :key="genus.label">
      <base-button @click="filterGenus(genus.label)" 
                   :mode="isSelected(genus.label) ? 'outline' :''">
        {{ genus.label }}
      </base-button>
    </li>
    <base-button @click="clearFilter()" mode="flat">
      Clear Filter
    </base-button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are my hero!!! I have been working at this for hours! Thank you so much!